# Objective C-Upload a file by selecting through the folders from the iphone to the drobpbox

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, cordova, dropbox-api

I need to know how to select a file from iphone from a particular folder and upload it to a particular folder in dropbox site. So my source path is:- var/mobile/...../myappname/IC1/20140203/test.txt

and destination path is :-   Dropboxhome/App/myappname/newfolder/test.txt

This is a dropbox plugin i created.

The code below can upload the file to dropbox that i will send through javascript and intake from index.html

```
- (void) upload:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
 {

CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;

NSString* javaScript = nil;

NSLog(@"Dropbox backup method is executing");

NSString *str=[command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"file:%@",str);

NSString *bundle=[[NSBundle mainBundle]bundlePath];

NSLog(@"path:%@",bundle);

NSString *destDir = @"/";

[[self restClient] uploadFile:str toPath:destDir withParentRev:nil fromPath:[bundle 

stringByAppendingString:str]];

pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];

javaScript = [pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:command.callbackId];

[self writeJavascript:javaScript];
}
```

javascript:

```
window.uploadCall=function(file)
         {
   cordova.exec(linkDropboxCB, linkDropboxFail,"DropboxPlugin", "upload",[file]);
         }
```

index.html:

```
    function upload()
    {
    var file=document.getElementById('file1').value 
    window.uploadCall(file);
    }
```

here 'file' gets value from textbox in which we manually write file name to upload.

I am done with creating a folder in dropbox,now i need to upload files into it.

Anybody who knows the solution please help.  :(  :)

Comment: uploadFile is the method in the Dropbox iOS Core SDK that you should use to upload files. Glancing at your code, it seems you already have that. What issue have you run in to at this point?

Comment: Yes, my code perfectly uploads my files but according to the destination path i have mentioned above I wanted to upload a file to the folder inside myappname ie,newfolder.This code of mine uploads only under myappname not inside any other folders in it!Hope you are clear with the problem of mine..Can you please help @Greg.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you currently have working code to upload to the root of your app folder (i.e., "/Apps/AppName/") but you want to upload to a subfolder of your app folder (e.g., "/Apps/AppName/newfolder/")? You should just be able to do this by with NSString *destDir = @"/newfolder";

Comment: Oh! its the same thing i worked with before,but it didn't work correctly,but now it worked,i guess something might be wrong by the way i have given it...Yes! it works,Thanks a trillion!!It was so simple!!Yipee....Thanks for your precious time @Greg :) :D